# Recent Visitors Of my Profile?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any api to find out which friend recently visited my profile?
I saw an app giving the time and name of the visitor. Is that possible?

(Graph API + PHP)

Thanks

Comment: No it is not possible,for security reason.............

Comment: You can get help from Facebook for user / account / site problems at https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=220217228006012 - this is not the correct forum for those questions (see http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions  for more information)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can't get this information from facebook, or from other sources.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Just wanted to know how they have done such an app saying recent profile visitors?

Comment: Because they are lying to ad get ad views and to harvest your data.

Comment: its is not possible in facebook because security purpose but in this option possible in orkut providing by google,

Comment: They are lying to get your personal information, email address for spam, etc., do not trust this apps!

Answer (score 0):

Hiding visitors 
comes under facebook privacy policy
so you cannot get those details and if you are getting will not be legal.
check `http://www.facebook.com/about/privacy/`